# How to return the object created in a function in FilePartMono after transfer in Spring Flux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Flux rest service with a method to transfer a file.  I want to return the Mono object created by my repository from this save function.  I am not sure how to do this.  I have the following method for my rest service:

```
 public Mono<Video> save(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        LOG.info("save called");
        counter++;
        String timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now().toString();

        return filePartMono
                .doOnNext(fp -> System.out.println("Received File : " + fp.filename()))
                .flatMap(fp -> {
                    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(videoFolder, timeStamp + "_" + fp.filename());

                    return fp.transferTo(file)
                            .doOnSuccess(f->createVideo(file, timeStamp)).
                                    thenReturn(video);//I added this line to see if it helped but didn't work

                })
                .doOnSuccess(video1 -> LOG.info("vide1: doOnSuccess: {}", video1))
                .thenReturn(new Video());  //here I want to return the object from createVideo() method. 

    }

    private Mono<Video> createVideo(File file, String timeStamp) {
        //path and thumbnailPath vars have been set
        Video video = new Video(path, thumbnailPath);

        Mono<Video> videoMono = videoRepository.save(video);
        LOG.info("saved video: {}", videoMono);
        return videoMono;
    }
```

Comment: Try changing the first `doOnSuccess` to just a `flatMap` and remove both the `thenReturn`

Comment: I removed both to this          return fp.transferTo(file)
                    .flatMap(f->createVideo(file, timeStamp));
but the createVideo() function is not getting executed

Comment: ah i see now, `transferTo` according to the api returns a `Mono<Void>` (i thought it returned a file) so try `transferTo(file).then(createVideo(file, timeStamp));`

Comment: if I do this transferTo(file).then(createVideo(file, timeStamp)); then the createVideo fails because it seems like file is not transferred yet successfully.  If I do this fp.transferTo(file).doOnSuccess(f-> createVideo(file, timeStamp)) then my createVideo() method successfully works.  However, I don't know how to return the video object from createVideo in this code:    fp.transferTo(file).doOnSuccess(f-> createVideo(file, timeStamp))
                                   .thenReturn(new Video());

Comment: Well your code does not compile, you are taking in a file parameter that is then not used. So im suspecting that what you have posted here is not the full story. I cant run your code. So i suggest you produce a small minimal reproducible example and explain your intent with your code step by step what it is you want to perform.

Comment: I have decided to return a id for now.